# I want to launch iTunes on an iPhone from a Geo Fencing trigger

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

I've a client looking to "launch" iTunes via messaging protocol when user enters a "geo fenced" area that offers content. Scenario: User has "wi-fi" enabled on their phone and walks into Starbucks.  Upon entering the store they are presented with a notification which says, "Do you want to download Adele's latest song, that has not been released yet?"

**How could you achieve this without:**

1. Creating an individual stand alone app that would have to be downloaded
2. Requiring the user to enter the password for the wi-fi network where content will be transferred?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Without having an app downloaded, this is impossible.

Comment: Imagine how miserable it would be to own a smartphone in a world where this were possible. E-mail spam is bad enough - imagine spam coming as intrusive push notifications that know your actual physical location! Your phone would never stop lighting up.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, this is not possible.